# XML serialization via javax.xml.bind

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using `javax.xml.bind.*` (which I believe you call `JAXB`) to serialize some fairly complex classes to XML.

My issue is that I seem to have to list namespaces everywhere I use a particular element. See:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.example.org/mynamespace")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.org/mynamespace2")
    public Ele ele1;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.org/mynamespace2")
    public Ele ele2;
}

public class Ele {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String attrib = "myattri";

    @XmlValue
    public String value = "value";
}
```

What I would prefer is for `Ele` to specify the namespace, so that I dont have to specify it everywhere else...

...is this possible?

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually based the link in Blaise Doughan's comment.

> Package Level Metadata
>
> We can easily qualify all the elements through the use of the package
>   level annotation @XmlSchema.  To specify a package level annotation,
>   create a class called package-info in the desired package (see
>   complete source below for an example).  Below we will set a default
>   namespace and specify that by default all elements are namespace
>   qualified.

I can add a `package-info.java` to the `example.ele` package with the following in it:

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.example.org/mynamespace2", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example.ele;
```

and put `Ele` in the `example.ele` package.